# Word for feeling conflicting emotions simultaneously

Tags: single-word-requests

I've been trying to think of an adjective that expresses having two (or perhaps more) conflicting emotions or opinions simultaneously. Can anyone think of one?

Comment: I am looking for words that actually combine more than one feeling ie anxiety and excitement. I made up a word which is Anxitement. Ambiv does not fit as it does not say what the feelings are.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ambivalent (*adj.*)

> ambivalence and ambivalency noun, originally psychol the concurrent
>   adherence to two opposite or conflicting views, feelings, etc about
>   someone or something. ambivalent adj. ambivalently adverb. ETYMOLOGY:
>   1912: from German Ambivalenz, from ambi-, modelled on 'equivalence';
>   see equivalent.

[Source](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?query=ambivalence&title=21st&sourceid=Mozilla-search)

Comment: That's the one! I've been trying to remember it for weeks.

Comment: No worries, thank Kryten from Red Dwarf for that one!

Comment: Seriously? You've got to be joking? I've sat and watched the entire box set over the past few days and I *still* didn't manage to remember that word.

Comment: <geek>It when he gets reprogrammed in series 7, I think. He struggles with it and just ends up doing silly faces</geek>

Comment: Ah, series 7. That explains it. I zoned out a little when watching the last two series, since it wasn't their best work.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly

Comment: No ambivalence there then ;)

Comment: I think of *ambivalent* as applying to less-significant options -- I'm *ambivalent* about whether to get pizza or tacos for lunch, but I'm *torn* or *conflicted* about whether to take this job or that one.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I'm not sure that that's the best example. Ambivalence implies that the two choices are opposite or conflict in some incompatible way. Whilst having pizza *and* tacos for lunch might make you overly full, they're hardly mutually exclusive.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: you'd be *uncertain* whether to pick pizza or tacos. People these days are misusing "ambivalent" to mean "uncertain". See etymonline's etymology for [ambivalence](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ambivalence).

Comment: @outis Interesting, I've never thought *ambivalent* meant *uncertain* (i.e. you're not sure which feeling is stronger/correct), but I've always thought it wasn't the same as *torn/conflicting* in that if you are *ambivalent* you don't have strong feelings one way or the other (each feeling is equivalently weak, you don't *care* whether either is correct/proper, or which decision is made.) But perhaps I've been misusing the word.

Answer (score 17):

'Torn' is often used eg. I was torn between loving her, and wanting to kill her.

Comment: That's a possibility, but I'm really looking for an adjective rather than a verb.

Comment: torn `is` an adjective...

Answer (score 11):

You could use "conflicted" possibly? Or "vie/vying," which is a verb even though you asked for an adjective.

Answer (score 6):

To [be in]/[have]/[get] **mixed feelings** about something:

> to have different conflicting feelings.

Comment: Mixed feelings fits an "I'm not sure about this" situation, rather than having two opposing emotions or opinions. I'm also convinced that it's a single word I'm looking for... I know I've heard it somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If I feel this way, I describe myself as "conflicted" or "confused".

I would not use "ambivalent" for two conflicting emotions; I describe myself as "ambivalent" if I am caught between multiple choices in a *decision* and don't feel strongly about any of them.

Comment: But [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ambivalent), for instance, has 'having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone'. ELU requires objective answers.

Answer (score 1):

Cognitive Dissonance...

The feeling of uncomfortable tension which comes from holding two conflicting thoughts in the mind at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *[dichotomous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomous)*:

> involving or proceeding from something with seemingly contradictory qualities

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is 'cognitive dissonance'.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance

Comment: Please provide some detail about your answer. Link-only answers are not considered as appropriate answers since they can get obsolete in case the contents of the link change.

Answer (score 0):

Soulrending, jiminied, jeckled, mentally eviscerated.

Whenever I cant find a word fit into a story I'm writing, I usually just write a short descriptive sentence, to fill in the blank and most times it sounds better than it would have originally. Or you could just make one up and hope it catches on: Shakespeare did it a lot.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE]. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).
Your post would be improved if it included references and an explanation of why it answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

*Turmoil* fits as a noun.  Unfortunately, the adjective *tumultuous* doesn't work as well.

Comment: To be in *[turmoil](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turmoil)* does not not actually require that one is ambivalent or conflicted.

Comment: 'Turmoil' might be result of the torn emotions, but is not specific to emotions or even the result of a choice. It simply means greatly disturbed (for whatever reason) eg. 'the city was in turmoil after the breakdown of government'.

Answer (score -6):

The proper word is *ambipathy*, a mixture of *sympathy* and *antipathy*, of *attraction* and *repulsion*.

Comment: This describes a particular kind of conflict, so doesn't fit the OP's bill. Also, it is a coined word that has little or no currency, possibly invented [here](http://www.emory.edu/INTELNET/predictionary.htm). And, your definition seems to have been taken from Urban Dictionary without attribution. ... Welcome to EL&U. :-)