# I need a sort of word to this definition; a label

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel that everyone has felt this at some point. It’s when you want to do something and don’t at the same time. I feel its a very common feeling but I don’t know if there’s a word that can label it. If there is I would like to know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for feeling conflicting emotions simultaneously](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49476/word-for-feeling-conflicting-emotions-simultaneously) Answers include 'ambivalent' / 'conflicted' 'having mixed feelings'.

Comment: I would call it "normal".

Answer (score 3):

**Ambivalent**

> : having or showing simultaneous and contradictory attitudes or
>   feelings toward something or someone : characterized by *ambivalence*

[Merriam-Webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ambivalent)

"She feels ambivalent about the promotion they're offering her because it means better pay, but longer hours."

Answer (score 2):

You're feeling ***[conflicted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conflicted)*** (M/W), "experiencing or marked by ambivalence or a conflict, especially of emotions "